# impled data fetching from IQueryable (EF) with blazor

Tags: entity-framework-core, blazor

Hello fellow blazor users.

I'm looking for a way to make EF imply what fields has to be fetched from the database based on a template that I will render with that data.

Something like this, where only `Name` field would be fetched.

```
<Component ParamSource=@DB.Set<Thing>() >
  <Template>
    <span>@context.Name</span>
  <Template/>
</Component>
```

Without doing this

```
<Component ParamSource=@DB.Set<Thing>().Select(item => new { item.Name })> 
  <Template><span>@context.Name</span><Template/>
</Component>
```

Is there a way to do so ? Where `.Select(item => new { item.Name })` part is implied from the data that `Template` uses.

I would expect simple LINQ SELECT with `System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<T, RenderFragment>> a = x => Template(x);` or `var b = (T item) => Template(item);` to work, but it doesn't. It fetches all the data.

Any ideas ?

Thanks.

I've tried these approaches (a and b inside `OnParametersSetAsync`)

```
@typeparam T
@code {
  [Parameter] public IQueryable<T> ParamSource { get; set; }
  [Parameter] public RenderFragment<T> Template{ get; set; }
  private List<RenderFragment>? list{ get; set; }
  override protected async Task OnParametersSetAsync()
  {
    await base.OnParametersSetAsync();
    System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<T, RenderFragment>> a = x => Template(x);
    var b = (T item) => Template(item);
    list = await ParamSource.Select(a).ToListAsync();
  }
}
@if (list != null)
{
  @foreach(var item in list)
  {
    @item
  }
}
```

Comment: Firstly, it is difficult (as in, you probably shouldn't) to reverse engineer declared HTML into C#. You should probably think about a more C#/Blazor approach - try building your desired columns and HTML from a higher-level declaration that can be shared.

Comment: Secondly, I would advise some separation between your HTML and your DB queries. Interacting with your EF context directly from your components will ensure that your application becomes increasinly difficult to maintain.

Comment: This is server blazor component, with which it is common to query database directly with no layer in between. Also (as point of the question) these two parts are tightly coupled, so whenever I change one I have to change the other. I doubt it would be wise to seperate them further than necesary.

Surely the most maintainable option would be to write it once, and that is the question I'm asking.

Comment: Regardless of how tightly coupled your solution is, point #1 is still valid - you are probably best served by having some common infrastructure at a higher level, which can then be shared by your UI and DB.

Comment: I also disagree that it is "common" to query the database directly from your UI. It might be presented that way in the most basic tutorials and blogs, but only to keep the demonstration as simple as possible - it is not an example of best practice, or what is commonly done in production.

Comment: Indeed most of my experience is from tutorials and such. HonestIy I cant even come up how your suggested seperation would work. 
I guess I could combine template with selection expression somewhere and fetch from somewhere else, but its the same coupling.